# Getting invalid syntax error while iterating list in python

Tags: python, list, loops

I am new to Python. I am trying to iterate a list in python and print the elements in this way :

```
for i in list
    print i
```

But I am getting an error like this :

```
for i in list
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have a similar code which is working fine :

```
list_unique = []
for i in list:
    if i not in list_unique:
        list_unique.append(i)
```

I couldnt understand the difference. Can some one help?

Comment: I don't think this question is too much off-topic. Yes it is only a typo, but a significant one that beginners will stumble over a lot and where the compiler doesn't help much. I think this question should stay open.

Comment: I know its a small syntactic error but it wasted a lot of time in investigating ..... not sure why it is marked as off topic..... please let it stay open

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a ":"

```
for i in list: #This one!
    print i
```

In Python you have to end each for, if, while, def, class and other statements that start a new block with a ":"